# Angular app in Tilt not live reloading with ng serve

Tags: angular-cli, tilt

I'm trying to develop an angular app using tilt on a local k3s cluster.  When I make a change to a file in local, I see that the change is taken into account by tilt, and I can see the change reflected in the pod.

The change isn't reflected in the browser though, despite running the command `ng serve --port 8080 --live-reload --watch`.

What am I doing wrong?

### Github issue

https://github.com/tilt-dev/tilt/issues/5039

### Notes (edit):

- on running "trigger update" from tilt the changes are taken into account, so i don't think that this is a cache issue
- I can see from the tilt logs that the command `ng serve --port 8080 --live-reload --watch` was indeed used to run the app

### Reproducible example

To replicate this, see minimal example [here](https://github.com/prestto/tilt_angular):

```sh
# install repo
git clone git@github.com:prestto/tilt_angular.git
cd tilt_angular

# run tilt
tilt up
```

Then:

- navigate to `http://localhost:8080/`
- make a change in `front/src/app/app.component.html`
- Hard refresh the browser at `http://localhost:8080/`

### Summary of files:

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.18.0-buster

WORKDIR /app

ADD ./front/package.json .
ADD ./front/package-lock.json .

RUN npm install

ADD ./front .

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Tiltfile

```py
k8s_yaml('./k8s/front.yml')
k8s_resource('bitbuyer-front', port_forwards=8080)
docker_build('user632716/bitbuyer-front:latest', '.', dockerfile='./docker/Dockerfile-bitbuyer-front',
  live_update=[
    # when package.json changes, we need to do a full build
    fall_back_on(['package.json', 'package-lock.json']),
    # Map the local source code into the container under /src
    sync('.', '/app'),
  ])
```

package.json

```json
{
    "name": "front",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "ng serve --port 8080 --live-reload --watch"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.9",
        "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/material": "^12.2.9",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
        "tslib": "^2.3.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.9",
        "@angular/cli": "~12.2.9",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
        "karma": "~6.3.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
        "typescript": "~4.3.5"
    }
}
```

K8s deployment

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bitbuyer-front
  labels:
    app: bitbuyer-front
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bitbuyer-front
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bitbuyer-front
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: bitbuyer-front
          image: user632716/bitbuyer-front:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "1000Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
            limits:
              memory: "1700Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          env:
            - name: ENV
              value: DEV
```

Comment: Please refer to https://github.com/tilt-dev/tilt/issues/5039

Comment: @HamzaRashid Thanks Hamza, I created that issue.  I'll add the link to the issue in the question.